# Piwik custom dimension in segment

Tags: aggregation, dimension, matomo, segment

We use Piwik cloud (innocraft.com) for analytics and have a custom dimension called channel_perm_id with scope Visit, it's called dimension1 and is transmitted via JS Tracking API. Using the piwik admin panel we can verify that the dimension is set correctly and transmitted by each visitor.

Now we want to query based on this dimension1 aka channel_perm_id:

```
curl -i https://###.innocraft.cloud/index.php?segment=dimension1==2ceb64954d4e46f49bc6afa310cf92f&token_auth=###&format=xml&date=today&period=day&idSite=8&module=API&method=VisitsSummary.get
```

The important part is

```
segment=dimension1==2ceb64954d4e46f49bc6afa310cf92f
```

which causes this query to return an empty response:

```
<result>
<nb_uniq_visitors>0</nb_uniq_visitors>
<nb_users>0</nb_users>
<nb_visits>0</nb_visits>
<nb_actions>0</nb_actions>
<nb_visits_converted>0</nb_visits_converted>
<bounce_count>0</bounce_count>
<sum_visit_length>0</sum_visit_length>
<max_actions>0</max_actions>
<bounce_rate>0%</bounce_rate>
<nb_actions_per_visit>0</nb_actions_per_visit>
<avg_time_on_site>0</avg_time_on_site>
</result>
```

Without the segment parameter the response looks like:

```
<result>
<nb_uniq_visitors>1</nb_uniq_visitors>
<nb_users>0</nb_users>
<nb_visits>6</nb_visits>
<nb_actions>0</nb_actions>
<nb_visits_converted>0</nb_visits_converted>
<bounce_count>6</bounce_count>
<sum_visit_length>2469</sum_visit_length>
<max_actions>0</max_actions>
<bounce_rate>100%</bounce_rate>
<nb_actions_per_visit>0</nb_actions_per_visit>
<avg_time_on_site>412</avg_time_on_site>
</result>
```

It looks like the custom dimension is somehow not aggregated in piwik.

But if we use the Live module (Live.getCounters instead of VisitsSummary.get), the query works fine.

So we think it has something to do with the scope maybe.

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find out how to segment by custom dimension? The docs don't explain this, and the segment list doesn't show custom dimensions, only custom variables. Quite confusing.

Comment: It's simply not possible, according to the founders. :-( We are doing it on our own, using InfluxDB and automatic report downsampling. It's a shame, that something like piwik does not support this.